# Getting an element inside an array and compare with a number

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

I need to compare between a number with an element inside an array. i am trying to loop for array but it did not work. i made an example here. i was thinking if i find the equal number in array it will work. i mean i expect blue color in example but its yellow. how can i make it work ?

```js
var rain =  [1072,1050,1053,1168,1080,1183,1171,1063,1083,1086,1089,1240,1273];
var number = 1072;

for (var j = 0; j < rain.length; j++) {
  if (number == rain[j]) {
    $('body').css('background', 'blue');
  } else {
    $('body').css('background', 'yellow');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Well, only the first number is the same. The remaining numbers are not, so the code in the `else` runs, causing the background to be yellow...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is yellow, because your `for`-loop keeps running, even after finding the `1072`. Basically, your function changes the color if the last, and only the last element in the `rain` array is the same as the given `number` as it's the last value looked at in the `for` loop.
If you want the loop to stop when the number is found you can add a return-statement there.

But there are two other approaches:

```
if(rain.indexOf(number) !== -1){
  //change color to yellow
}else{
  //change color to blue
}
```

or, as Sterling Archer said, using `includes`

Comment: thanks for the answer. can you explane why we are using not equal -1 ? i am new on JS.

Comment: All arrays have the function `indexOf` which returns the index where the given element was found. If it isn't found, it returns -1. So in your case, if it is *not* -1, this means, the number was found in the array.

Comment: Thank you my friend

Answer (score 2):

You can just use [Array.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to do this. The issue with your code is no break statement if true, so it keeps running and eventually ends on the final number, which is the decider.

```
var rain = [1072,1050,1053,1168,1080,1183,1171,1063,1083,1086,1089,1240,1273];
var number = 1072;
if (rain.includes(number)) {
    $('body').css('background', 'blue');
} else {
    $('body').css('background', 'yellow');
}
```

Comment: Of course, if you need to support IE still, this won't work without a polyfill, but I feel bad for anyone who has to support IE still :).